# Tengo que hacer un metodo usando recursividad en el cual yo le doy una cadena

Tags: java, netbeans

El cual  me imprime -1 si no hay mayusculas en la cadena o si es que las hay debe mostrar el indice en donde esta la mayuscula, tengo el codigo pero por alguna razon decide ignorar la recursividad y solo tomar el ultimo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "#hoLa";
        System.out.println(mayus (str,str.length()-1));
     
    }  
    private static int mayus(String str, int indice)
    {        
            int mayuscula = 0;
            if ((Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(indice))) == false && (indice>0))
            {
                mayus(str,indice -1);`Esto no lo toma y solo toma el ultimo caracter`
                mayuscula = -1;
                
            }
            else if ((Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(indice))) == true && (indice >0))
            {
                
                mayuscula = indice;
            
            }
            return mayuscula;
    }
```

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí bien  cuando no hay mayúsculas devuelve -1, pero que pasa si hay varias mayúsculas entonces no es un índice son varios aclararme esto

Answer (score 0):

Agrego código con la recursividad corregida.

```
private static int mayus(String str, int indice) {
    // 1. iniciar la variable en -1
    int mayuscula = -1;

    if ((Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(indice))) == false && (indice > 0)) {
        // 2. asignar el resultado de la función a la variable
        mayuscula = mayus(str, indice - 1);

    } else if ((Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(indice))) == true && (indice > 0)) {

        mayuscula = indice;

    }
    return mayuscula;
}
```

Forma simplificada:

```
private static int mayus(String str, int indice) {

        // Caso base: fin de la cadena retornar -1
        if (indice == str.length()) return -1;

        // Caseo base:si el caracter es mayúscula retornar el indice
        if (Character.isUpperCase(str.charAt(indice))) return indice;

        // paso recursivo
        return mayus(str, indice + 1);
    }
```

Comment: Y que pasa cuando hay más de una mayúscula?

Comment: Pues eso que lo diga quién hizo la pregunta. Por el momento hay un error en la recursión.